# Storing columns on disk and reading rows

Tags: c++, file, matrix, io

So I have a C++ code that finds the inverse of a square matrix. The inverse is full and it would be bad to keep it all in memory because I am working with hundreds of thousands of columns. My code generates the columns one by one. After finding the inverse, the rest of my code requires the rows one by one. Ideally, I would like to proceed as follows:

Repeat:
1) find a column 
2) store it on the disk
3) delete the column from memory.

Repeat:
1) read a row from the disk
2) process it (it is basically the objective function of a linear program)
3) delete the row from memory.

One way of doing that is writing the matrix in the file as it is.. Meaning, I write the first column as an "actual" column in the file, then I write the second next to it (which would be a bit less efficient), and so on. The last column will take O(n^2) to write if I'm not mistaken. Doing this makes reading the rows very easy though. The other way is to write the columns as rows then reading the columns later on.. But again, the last column will take O(n^2) to read. A third approach is to use n files, but opening and closing n files is inefficient.

Any ideas on how to approach such a problem? Maybe I have to use databases (possibly SQL) to make my reading and writing O(1) per entry?

Thank you.

Comment: You can `seek` in a binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned solution with `fseek` is good. However, it can be very slow for large matrices (as disks don't like random access, especially very far away). To speed up things, you should use blocking.

I'll show a basic concept, and can explain it further if you need.

First, you split your matrix into blocks of equal size, like so:
[image: Split1]

Block size should be calculated in such way that column or row of ***blocks*** can fit into RAM.

Next, you keep column of blocks in memory, and copy here first generated `blocksize` columns. Here yellow part is what you keep in memory, and orange - your next generated column:
[image: SplitColumns]

After you finish with the first `blocksize` columns, dump them into separate files (for my image, you can name such files "A1", "A7" and "A13"), and start again with the next column of blocks.

When you need this matrix as rows later, invert this procedure. Read from prepared files (for example, "A1", "E1", "I1" and "M1") first row of blocks, and process it row by row:

[image: SplitRows]

Comment: Dividing the matrix in blocks that fit in memory is a good idea to speed up things, provided that you can apply your algorithm step by step, I mean on these chunks. Congrats.

Comment: Oh! nice. Thanks a lot.
What would happen if the matrix is sparse and I just want to store the nonzero elements? So, the columns I'm storing are sparse, and so I'll be reading sparse rows later on.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a square matrix, then it is easy to write a random access file. For example, if you store the matrix by rows, as in...

```
FILE * f = fopen( FileName, "w+b" );
for(int i = 0; i < MaxRows; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < MaxColumns; ++i) {
        fwrite( &v[ i ][ j ], 1, sizeof( double ), f );
    }
}
```

Now you can go wherever you want. Just take into account that you have to apply a formula each time:

```
pos = ( MaxColumns * rowNumber ) + colNumber;
```

In order to position yourself in the file, you have to use `fseek()`, which counts in bytes, not in elements.

Say you want to go to the first element of the third column. The position would be...

```
int pos = ( MaxColumns * 2 ) + 0;
```

So now you can fseek to that position:

```
fseek( f, pos * sizeof( double ), SEEK_SET );
```

And, say, read the value:

```
double value;
fread( &value, 1, sizeof( double ), f );
```

So my answer is: once you have the matrix saved in disk, you can manipulate it without limits, without any worries about how much it occupies.

Just don't forget to close the file:

```
fclose( f );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh! awesome! Thank you very much. I'll try that just now. cheers.